# Couldn't find Superset Repository folder in my PC

Tags: visualization, open-source, apache-superset

After Installing "Apache Superset" (Installation from Scratch) using Ubuntu terminal in Windows OS, I Couldn't find where the superset repository folder stored in my PC? How can I find the superset repository?

I have installed Apache superset using this link: https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch

I tried searching in all the folders in Local disk - C. But I couldn't find any folder related to Apache Superset.